# Issue trying filter within Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am finishing a last piece of this mini-app where I'm pulling names from a text file.  When pulling the names from a ..txt I am filtering out certain prefixes like *eft, *nsm with code like below.

```
$lines = (Get-Content C:\temp\PROD\Repeat.txt  -totalcount 200)

$flines = $lines|?{$_ -notlike "*eft", "nsm*", "*" , "*" .... }

$objOutputBox.Text = $flines
```

The problem I'm having is that it is only grabbing the "*eft" and not the rest of them.  I thought I could filter an array of strings with this structure?  What am I missing here if you do not mind?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You cannot apply `-notlike` like this. You'll have to use the operator multiple times:

```
-notlike '*eft' -notlike 'nsm*' ...
```

But a better way would probably be a regular expression:

```
-notmatch 'eft$|^nsm|...'
```

Comment: You don't need the intermediate variable `$flines` there, though. You can just assign the pipeline to `$objOutputBox.Text`. Also, I hope the `'*'` arguments to `-notlike` were placeholders, not actual operands.

Comment: Okay I will pipeline it.  Yeah they are placeholders..  Thanks again it is highly appreciated.